# Swift 5 - textField.endEditing(true) crashing the app

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uitextfield, uikeyboard, swift5

I'm using Number Pad keyboard and I programmed, when there is no text, when you press "Delete button" to trigger the function .endEditing , but the app crashes with this error:

`Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.`

.resignFirstResponder() also crash with this error

I've tried adding a delay timer, but also crash.

changed to .endEditing(false) also crash.

Any suggestions without adding UINavigationController ? I can't afford to use UINavigationController, since my app must use the whole screen and I need all the space on it.

Answer (score 0):

I've added UINavigationController and I hide it... If there are more options, feel free to share it :)